# Use a template file from a plugin in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to develop a plugin which includes a file from a template. At this moment my code view is like this:

```
/* Add a query var for template select, and and endpoint that sets that query var */
add_action( 'init', 'wpse22543_rewrite_system' );

function wpse22543_rewrite_system() {
    global $wp, $wp_rewrite;
    $wp->add_query_var( 'template' );   
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'kalkulator_leasingowy', EP_ROOT );
    $wp_rewrite->add_rule(  '^/kalkulator_leasingowy/?$', 
        'index.php?template=kalkulator_leasingowy', 'bottom' );
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}


/* Handle template redirect according the template being queried. */
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse22543_select_template' );

function wpse22543_select_template() {
    global $wp;
    $template = $wp->query_vars;

    if ( array_key_exists( 'template', $template ) && 
        'kalkulator_leasingowy' == $template['template'] ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set( 'is_404', false );

        include( get_stylesheet_directory().'/kalkulator_leasingowy.php' );
        exit;
    }
}


function prefix_movie_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'kalkulator_leasingowy', 'index.php?template=kalkulator_leasingowy', 'top' );
}
 
add_action( 'init', 'prefix_movie_rewrite_rule' );
```

This code runs very fine and includes the template file, but my template (header.php and footer.php) by default uses a [Visual Composer](https://visualcomposer.com/) and when I use this code on a page, view this:

[image]

[image]

Visual Composer works good on all pages without a /kalkulator_leasingowy.

How I can include a VC into /kalkulator_leasingowy as well?

---

#### File kalkulator_leasingowy.php

```
<?php
get_header();
?>
<div class="main-wrapper"> 
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="row">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: As I understand the question, since the template is being used, but the output isn't what you expect, your actual issue lies in the `kalkulator_leasingowy.php` file, not the template code you've shared above.  In that case, without seeing the template file code, it's hard to assess why VC isn't being rendered correctly - can you share that code here as well?

Comment: Okey, I added this file. If you can please to look it but is a very simple file. I don't know I can add the header.php file because its a theme buy on themeforest. Problem is simple, All theme files work fine but I add "fake/virtual page" from my plugin and add kalkulator_leasingowy.php to theme files, unfortunately Visual composer not work on this page :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really understanding where you are trying to render custom Visual Composer code since your template file doesn't have any in it.

But based on your edit, it looks like you might actually want to be using a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). These make it very easy to add new template files to the parent theme without editing any of the parent's code and eliminate the need for most of your complex code.

If perhaps you are injecting the Visual Composer code from somewhere else, make sure you are applying the content filters rather than just inserting or echoing to the front end.

```
 $content = '<div id="my_custom_content">[vc shortcode contents here]</div>';
 echo apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

This will make sure the end content is filtered and rendered appropriately. You might read [this related answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/173847/10269) for more information.